# What are real advantages of brake hose junction connectors?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I just received my new brake callipers and handles.  They come pre-assembled with hoses and a "hose junction connector".  These are the same as Dan Lloyd has in the below video:

I understand the advantage of these when there is a need to work on the hosing without the need to unwrap bartape.  However I can't really think of a scenario where I would work on the hoses and still worry about the bartape as well.  I do however see scenarios where these connectors would scratch my frame or just be plain ugly.

Before I spend money to replace something potentially useful: what are some real life advantages of using these connectors?

Comment: Consider that the bike comes in a box, with the handlebar detached.

Comment: As per Swifty's answer: not messing with the fittings at the lever side is a real advantage.  I'll try and see if I can shorten the hose connected the lever somewhat and then place these junctions below my handlebars, under the bar tape.  That would take it out of sight and will stabilise it.  if placed strategically, I expect it shouldn't affect my grip will riding on the tops of the bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your own bike, you would probably only do that one time, when the bike is new (to you) and setup opposite to your preference.

The big advantage in this situation is that you shouldn’t have to unwrap that lovely fresh bar tape to do the job, and you are undoing specially designed connectors, instead of the compression fittings at the lever. There’s less to go wrong, certainly no need to fit new fittings or shorten the hose for them, just a couple of spanners are required. More lay-user friendly.

Otherwise, If you had a rental fleet and foreign customers, you could swap the hoses around if any customer requests it, then back again. I assume; I don’t know how many swaps the connectors could handle, but it would be preferable to swapping at the lever end. (Quicker, easier, no need to shorten the hose for new compression fittings).

Comment: " instead of the compression fittings at the lever". I think this is a true advantage.  Accidentally stripping the thread on my levers would be really painful...  I'll cover the connectors in some shrink tubing and hope it's not too ugly and will not scratch my bike.

Answer (score 2):

More recently, fully internally routed brake hoses (through the headset) are becoming popular.  These connectors (when installed in the bike head tube), could be useful for servicing these kind of bikes.